# Is there a name for this differential equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I am studying the temperature $T$ of a wire that generates heat due to current flow. The electric resistivity is temperature dependent, so I end up with the equation:

$$\Delta T + \lambda T = f $$

If $\lambda = 0$ then it's the Poisson equation, but is there a name for this PDE in the case of $\lambda\neq 0$ ?

Comment: Do you mean $\nabla^2=\Delta$? If so this is the Helmholtz equation when $\lambda>0$.

Comment: @podiki The question would be utter nonsense with a $\nabla$, so I edited it.

Comment: It would just be an inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation.

Comment: Thanks @podiki for your comment, yes I meant that. Thank you and K.defaoite for the name of the PDE if you write an answer I can mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as the [inhomogeneous Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Inhomogeneous_Helmholtz_equation).